# AudioContext: Sound not playing in Chrome, but working in Internet Explorer but workers when I comment out createMediaElement?t

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

Trying to get audio to play through Chrome. I have a functioning piece of code that works on Internet Explorer but not Chrome... I am able to get sound to play as long on Chrome as I comment out the line that says

`var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);`

-I've tried passing in Audio as two different forms (both through an HTML audio tag as well as a HTMLMediaElement through Javascript (as detailed here [Chrome - createMediaElementSource not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35303362/chrome-createmediaelementsource-not-working)). Both work fine as long as, again, the createMediaElementSource() is commented out.
-If I remove the lines

```
  var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  audioSrc.connect(analyser);
  audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);


  var bufferSize = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferSize);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);
```

sound DOES play in chrome.

Here's my code below (change the mp3 file to any mp3 file you have handy). Any help would be appreciated...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
html, body, #svg {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>


<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = 'laugh_8.mp3';
  audio.controls = true;
  document.body.appendChild(audio);

  var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext ||  window.webAudioContext)();


  var audioSrc = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  audioSrc.connect(analyser);
  audioSrc.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);


  var bufferSize = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(bufferSize);
  analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);


  var svgHeight = window.innerHeight - 100;
  var svgWidth = window.innerWidth - 10;


  var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', svgWidth)
    .attr('height', svgHeight);

  document.write("Code is working.");

  var circle = svg.append('circle')
        .attr('r', 20)
        .attr('cx', 50)
        .attr('cy', svgHeight-100)
        .attr('fill', 'black');


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) so people can help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @Herohtar Sorry, new to StackOverflow! Original question has been edited